# Why is image request generating a 302?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm using PHP to generate the following image element:

```
<img id="uploaded-image" src="http://localhost/gonzo/plans/image/123/tablemap.png" />
```

This image URL is routed through my PHP MVC framework to the following function, which grabs the image from my db and prints it:

```
    public function image($hexCode='',$fileName) {

    if (!$this->validRequest('get')) return false;

    Framework::loadModel('plan_model.php');
    $plan = new PlanModel();

            // Return image data from Blob field in db.
    $image = $plan->getImage('123');

    if ($image) {
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        print $image;
        die;
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

The request generates a 302, with the wrong location and content-type headers:

[image]

The browser does not display the image where this image tag is on the page.  But, when the image URL is typed directly into the address bar, the image is displayed.

Why would my server be generating a 302 when loading the image into an  tag, but generating a 200 when the image URL is typed directly into the address bar?  I'm running Apache on Windows.

Comment: i'd verify that your function actually gets called, and that you have an image, and that no other headers are sent before it. perhaps your MVC framework generates the 302?

Comment: Any mod_rewrite action occurring?

Comment: Yes, I do have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: How are you checking that the image URL is sending back a 200 when typed into the address bar? (Rather than generating a 302 which then redirects to a 200 page.) And you say "typed" -- have you definitely tried a direct copy and paste, rather than typing? Can you try something like wget from the command line and watch to see if it shows up a redirect?

Comment: When the URL for the image is pasted into the address bar, Firebug shows a 200 code with the correct Content-Type header - but I'll check to see if a 302 is happening first.

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior isn't possible at all - since the server **doesn't know** a bit about how an **URL is embedded in a web-page**.

Provide more details of the actual call of the PHP-script: Print environmental details - $_GET, $_POST and $_SERVER - to a log file.

It might be helpful to [register a tick-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) and trace each executed statement to a log-file.

Check your PHP sources.

Comment: That's precisely why I'm so confused!

Comment: Sure! But don't just check what happens in your browser, but verify what exactly happens in your script.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was caused by a strange concurrency problem.  My framework was still processing the first request (which generated the page containing the img element) while the browser requested the image.

In other words, when the browser requested the image, it was still receiving output from the first request to the script.  This made things go wacky.

Output buffering didn't solve the problem, but possible solutions are:

1. Pause execution of the second (image request) script for a sufficient amount of time to let the first one complete.
2. Host the image serving script on a separate subdomain.